# Exchange2010 has Private Machine Name and IP in outbound SMTP - How to remove?

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010, smtp-headers

We have a domain (domain.local) that has IP Addresses in the 10.10.10.* range.  In the outbound SMTP server traffic, I see the internal machine name (exchange.domain.local), and the internal ip address (10.10.10.55).

The question is, how do you remove this header from exchange, or change it to have the external machine name/ip addresses.

I am not talking about the HELO / EHLO handshake as part of the protocol.

Please help.

Comment: What do you use for your external SMTP server?  Is it an Exchange edge server, or something else?  Are you just trying to have the e-mail headers not have any evidence of coming from the Exchange server?

Comment: What header exactly are you talking about? Can you post a sample?

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the name from INTERNAL to "valid" fqdn:

1. Open EMC
2. Expand "Server Configuration", navigate to "Hub Transport"
3. At the lower section of the middle pane, double-click "Default "netbiosnameofyourserver""
4. Adjust the proper name in the "Specify the FQDN ..."

No need to restart anything. The setting will be picked up almost instantaneously.

In regards to IP, you would need to use device that will be able to mask and replace IP in the outgoing packets Source NAT. Any decent firewall these days will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the Hub Transport rule, there is an option about Header replace.

Comment: It is a single-instance exchange server, that is, the exchange server serves as the entire mail subsystem.

Comment: Ariel,  I have been unable to find reference material regarding how to set this type of a rule up... do you have any pointers or information you could share?